# Is it okay to have a series in a series? If not then is there another way to structure it?

Tags: sentence

"In a research process you need to identify the problem, review related literature, set the research questions, objectives and hypothesis, choose the study design and sample design, collect, process and analyze data, and write the report."

This is a series and the series inside it are:

> set the research questions, objectives and hypothesis

> choose the study design and sample design

> collect, process and analyze data

I think the sentence looks ugly and somewhat incomprehensible. Is there a better way to structure this sentence? Is the series in a series allowed?

Comment: _the sentence looks ugly and somewhat incomprehensible_ - You seem to have answered your own question. You can do it but it's unwieldy. Why are you trying to do it all in one sentence?

Comment: For complex sentences like this, semi-colons are sometimes used.

Comment: Can you use bullet points instead? Potentially with sub-bullets too?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a semi-colon: "In a research process you need to identify the problem; review related literature; set the research questions, objectives and hypothesis; choose the study design and sample design; collect, process and analyze data; and write the report."